# What to do if the question says "I'm too tired..."

Tags: discussion, review

In the first posts review queue, I saw a question saying "I'm too tired to solve this ...". If I see such question again, what is the best action?

Comment: Perhaps comment "I'm also too tired to solve this." :-) .

Comment: Treat it as any other question. If it bothers you, consider not policing people's reasons for posting questions.

Comment: @Matt:There are people on this site who try to main its reputation, as a site, and part of it is making sure it doesn't turn into a homework dump. While arguably that ship had sailed, it's not too late to at least try and have users try to write proper questions.

Comment: @Asaf I'd say that if it qualifies as a contribution of useful content to the site, who cares if someone posted it because they were too tired to do their own homework? If the content is not useful, by all means vote to close, but it shouldn't be because you don't like the reason it was posted.

Comment: @Asaf But of course this is the old argument, which I'm sure everyone is tired of. The people who are working contrary to the site's original intent appear to be winning, they have moderators on their side (I don't necessarily mean you, but I do have at least one specific moderator in mind. I won't elaborate since I've never had a suspension and I'm not sure what it takes to get one, but I also don't need to find out).

Comment: @Matt: (1) You suggest that one should consider voting to close, sure, but that wasn't the tone of your original comment. (2) You claim to have knowledge about the original intent of the website, having joined in 2014, when the site was quite established, and ignoring the fact that even at its very core and start there was a lot of debate and issue about "the original intent". (3) Arguing with a moderator is not how you get a suspension, if nothing else I think that all the moderators on the team are open to criticism and to hear the community's opinion.

Comment: @Asaf I don't mean to imply I know the original intent from personal experience, I mean the philosophy of stack exchange as a whole, to be a repository. In 2014 there was similar rampaging destruction of content as there is now, led by Normal Human, but it doesn't seem that it was as bad as it is now even so.

Comment: @Matt: Databases that don't normally undergo maintenance die. They become bloated, useless, people stop searching and just add repeated information. Maintaining a repository means also pruning *badly written* content. It means closing, deleting, and editing. The philosophy is to somehow let the past be, and things from a sufficiently long time ago might be left untouched (until disturbed, anyway). But new content *should* be under more scrutiny.

Comment: @Asaf I don't necessarily disagree with that in principle. I might have different standards. But it seems you might also disagree with what is currently happening with mass deletion of old questions.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I have to agree with Matt. There’s an inherent expectation in this meta question that there is more to the fictitious question than the OP saying “I’m too tired to do this,” — we’re expecting the post to have no context and no attempt at a solution. Of course, given this, the question should be closed/deleted/etc. However, there’s no reason why a priori this should be true. The question should be treated as any other. If it’s still a good question, upvote it; if it needs editing, edit it; and so on.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I guess I just disagree that such a post *necessitates* the label of “homework dump.”

Comment: @MattSamuel I disagree with your position. Peer review is an integral part of scientific publishing, and what we do here is NOT that different (even though we are not really pushing the boundaries of human knowledge). Database maintenance here is essential here for much the same reasons that peer reviewing is. Bringing a semblance of order to the chaos that would otherwise result.

Comment: I get the impression that you are a bit younger than I am, so you may not remember what happened in the age of usenet newsgroups, sci.math in particular. It was not pretty. In a blog Joel Spolsky (the CEO and co-founder of StackExchange) compared it (the same thing happened in the usenet groups dedicated to programming) to *Lord of the flies*. Simply because we have an unlimited amount of disk space does not mean that anything goes.

Comment: @SantanaAfton I see your point. However, I am hard pressed to think of reasons other than *a homework due in a few hours* for posting a question including that phrase. I do concede that I use that excuse for posting a hint in *a comment* occasionally. My timezone is somewhat distant from that of the North American askers, and my addiction to the site does that to me every now and then.

Comment: @SantanaAfton: Why do you think it is a fictitious question? (I took the time and effort to locate the question in question, it's just not a 100% accurate quote.) I think that the lack of concrete link makes this more of a Rorschach test as to what do you think a question saying "I'm too tired to solve this" would be like. Some people think it's a homework dump, others think it's in fact an excellently written question. Such is life.

Comment: I can't find that question anymore. If you search "I am too tired", it gives you some examples. Of course, the next such question I will see will be probably different than the one I saw yesterday. If there is no general sollution, can be such questions at least divided into some cases?

Comment: The problem is that "I'm so tired of trying to solve this" can fit into **too many** situations, some merit a closing vote and others merit an upvote instead. There's no "one size fits all" here.

Comment: Okay, can you please tell me in which situations it should be closed and in which situations not?

Comment: @Hume2 I agree with Asaf's comment above that you can't really classify the questions which include a phrase like "I'm too tired to solve this ...". Although I've seen phrases like this mostly used in PSQ type questions as an excuse to not show what (if any) work was done or provide any other sort of context, I don't think my perception of the quality of the question will generally change very much on whether or not this phrase is used. I suggest reading the question and determining, overall, what you consider it's quality to be, with no undue emphasis on this phrase if it's included.

Comment: @MattSamuel could you *quantify* your claims regarding mass deletions? If a serious debate is to be had this seems important. Say, starting from which percentage do you think it is mass deletion?

Comment: @quid *Quantify?* What do I look like, a mathematician? In seriousness, I can't attest to the quantity being large compared to the total number of questions. But I consider hundreds to be mass deletions, and I'd estimate given my anecdotal observations that it's at least of that order.

Comment: @MattSamuel "hundreds"  over what period of time? In total? Per day? What else? Assuming total, given that there is more than a million questions on the site "hundreds" will be less than 1 in thousand. If that is your opinion I encourage you to be up-front about this and to frame your critique in that way. It would also mean that you seem to think that there is not even one question per day newly asked that should be deleted. Do you actually think this?

Comment: @quid I'm focused mostly on the deletion of old questions.

Comment: @MattSamuel define "old". I mean it ought to be possible for you to articulate a precise objection. And if you cannot then it would seem apt to present it as such, as some vague sentiment that you are unable to make precise. There is an actual risk in users believing all kinds of stuff just because other users repeat something all the time. Mass deletions of old questions happen. No one knows how many, no one knows what old means. But certainly it sounds scary. ;-)

Comment: @MattSamuel Since I see that you have discussed with quid deleting old questions, I'll add a link to a discussion in chat where we attempted to look at some stats from Data Explorer: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19138/conversation/some-stats-on-old-deleted-questions (Although I am not sure to which extent the queries created there are satisfactory for the purpose of getting useful data for further analysis.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best way to deal with this is to mentally remove this statement from the question. If the "modified" version merits a certain kind of vote, then cast it.

(By certain, I mean delete/close/up/down/left/right/left/right/jab, of course.)

Comment: up/up/down/down/left/right/left/right/A/B?

Comment: HADOUKEN! (well, that would be left/right/left/right/punch)